# Attachment preview has quit working in Gmail

Tags: gmail

When receiving emails with pictures like .jpg attachments, Gmail no longer is previewing these, instead giving me the following message and associated options:

> Apologies. There is no preview available.
>
> *Download* or *Connect More Apps*

It then goes on to list connected apps and suggested third party apps. I have tried downloading the suggested apps and it still does not work. I also cannot seem to find where these "apps" are stored so that I can try removing and reinstalling them. What steps can I take to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue, but this was due to the email being in the spam folder. As soon as I got it back to my inbox, the preview was back